# How to define a function which accept both Seq[T] and ParSeq[T] as parameter?

Tags: scala, parallel-collections

In many cases, I want to apply the same `filter` or `map` function to a `Seq` or `ParSeq` collection. However I don't want to write the code twice.

```
def fun(data:ParSeq[String], num_start:Int,num_end:Int) = {
    data filter { x=>
      val temp = extract_number(x)
      num_start <= temp && temp <= num_end
    }
  }
```

Like the code above, for a `Seq[String]` I need to apply `fun`, I have to rewrite it again and the content are exactly the same.
How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GenSeq[String]`.

Both `ParSeq` and `Seq` extends `GenSeq`, this is typically used in order to have functions that will use parallel or sequential operations depending on the type of collection you pass to them.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
def fun(data:GenSeq[String], num_start:Int,num_end:Int) = {
    data filter { x=>
      val temp = extract_number(x)
      num_start <= temp && temp <= num_end
    }
  }
```

GenSeq is a `trait` and it is extended [or implemented] by both `ParSeq` and `Seq`