# Getting `lub` with Minimal Output?

Tags: scala

Looking at [How to define a function which accept both Seq[T] and ParSeq[T] as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42826571/how-to-define-a-function-which-accept-both-seqt-and-parseqt-as-parameter), I figured `lub` (Least Upper Bound) was appropriate

However it gives the following, long output:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
scala> lub( List( typeOf[scala.collection.Seq[Int]],
                  typeOf[scala.collection.parallel.ParSeq[Int]] ) )
res1: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = scala.collection.GenSeq[Int]{def ...
```

It looks like `GenSeq` is the `lub`. However, how can I get the type alone, i.e. `GenSeq[Int]`, excluding other details?

Answer (score 1):

The `Type` you get by calling `lub` is the actual LUB (Least Upper Bound), asking for the "type alone" is misleading, that one is already the correct LUB.

`GenSeq[Int]` is an upper bound but not the LUB, it is a superclass of the LUB.

That cryptic type is actually a [`RefinedType`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala-reflect/scala/reflect/api/Types$RefinedType.html) so you can obtain the list of its superclasses:

```scala
import reflect.runtime.universe._

def unRefined(tp: Type): List[Type] = tp match {
  case rtp: RefinedType => rtp.parents
  case _ => ???
}
```

Going back to your example, it gives you:

```scala
scala> unRefined(res1)
res2: List[reflect.runtime.universe.Type] = List(scala.collection.GenSeq[Int])
```